# Coded UI configure whether or not to automatically check value

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have seen somewhere, but cannot remember where, that you can indicate whether Coded UI should automatically check the value of the onscreen object which has been changed. For instance, if I do

blahblahUIMaap.txtUserName.Text = "My User Name";

Coded ui will test that the Text property contains what I have set it to. But I can change the behavior of Coded UI. But I cannot for the life of me remember how to do this. I thought it was in PlayBack.PlaybackSettings, but I don't see anything there. Google does not know either. Or at least not in the manner that have asked. :)

Thanks

S

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Playback.PlaybackSettings.SkipSetPropertyVerification = true;